# Create Custom Password Policy on AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

I have an active directory on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

How to create custom password policy on Active Directory? I do not mean standard fine-grained policy with just length of password and number of remembered passwords. I mean I need to prohibit to use names, surname, cities etc. as password.

How to do that?

Please assist.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need additional software for that. Google password policy enforcer.